# showing this error while integrating flutter module as pod in swift

Tags: swift, flutter, module, frameworks, integration

```
Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets
```

created podspec using this command

```
flutter build ios-framework --cocoapods --output=some/path/MyApp/Flutter/
```

used like this in pod file

```
pod 'Flutter', :podspec => 'some/path/MyApp/Flutter/Release/Flutter.podspec'
```

here is the code for swift for calling

```
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, ObservableObject {
  let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "FlutterEngine")

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      // Runs the default Dart entrypoint with a default Flutter route.
        flutterEngine.run(
          withEntrypoint: "", initialRoute: "/")
      GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine);
      return true;
    }
}
```